# SQL how to count alias as a total

Tags: count, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
    LoginName as caseowner,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NULL AND accountsDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS Active,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('complicated', 'multiple', 'NONE') AND completionDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS t,
    SUM(CASE WHEN datesent IS NOT NULL AND completionDate IS NOT NULL AND accountsDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Setup],
    SUM(SELECT(Activecases + t + setup)) AS [total]
FROM        
    Case WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE     
    casekey NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%'
    AND typecode = 'r'
GROUP BY 
    LoginName 
ORDER BY 
    LoginName ASC
```

I want to have a 'total' column containing a sum of the 'active','t' and 'setup' sum queries. 
 can someone point me in the right direction and tell me where im going wrong?
thanks

Comment: Syntax error at line 3 at `null'THEN`.

Comment: Careful placing NOLOCK hint with aggregations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your query in a CTE (or subquery) and do the totalling on the outside:

```
;WITH CTE_Totals AS (    
    SELECT 
        LoginName as caseowner,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NULL AND accountsDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS Active,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('complicated', 'multiple', 'NONE') AND completionDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS t,
        SUM(CASE WHEN datesent IS NOT NULL AND completionDate IS NOT NULL AND accountsDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Setup]
    FROM        
        Case WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE     
        casekey NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%'
        AND typecode = 'r'
    GROUP BY 
        LoginName
)
SELECT
    caseowner,
    Active,
    t,
    Setup,
    Active + t + Setup AS Total
FROM
    CTE_Totals
ORDER BY 
    LoginName ASC;
```

Comment: thank you  @chrispickford makes it much easier totalling on the outside